# UIScrollView imageViewDidEndZooming not being called

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiscrollview

I have this subclass of UIScrollView:

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

And I have those delegate methods

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale(float)aScale{
    NSLog(@"zoomed");
}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView{
    NSLog(@"willzoom");
}
```

When I zoom in MyScrollView viewForZoomingInScrollView is called but scrollViewDidEndZooming never gets called.

Any idea why??

Comment: Where and how have you declared these delegate methods? And where are you calling them? If you declare custom delegate methods, you are responsible of calling them from within your MyScrollView class.

Comment: Sorry... I pasted the wrong code. Now it's fixed

Comment: What about scrollViewWillBeginZooming ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, completely revised answer based on your comment below.  This may just be another typo, but your method signature is missing the final parameter.

Instead of:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale{
    NSLog(@"zoomed");
}
```

You should have:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)aScale{
    NSLog(@"zoomed");
}
```

Comment: My mistake. I cut&pasted the wrong lines. I fixed the question

Comment: My code is based on that one. For simplifying the question i changed the code inside the delegates for NSLog calls. The result is the same: viewForZoomingInScrollView is called but scrollViewDidEndZooming is not

Comment: Damn.... you are right.Typo again :-( I have it just you said I should but it's still not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump the thread, but it is a very important question. You don't say whether you are implementing a separate pinch gesture recogniser or using the built in zooming of UIScrollView. From my own researches I have found that if you just use UIScrollView to zoom it calls viewForZoomingInScrollView to get the view you want to zoom. Then it calls scrollViewWillBeginZooming, then as it zooms it calls scrollViewDidZoom repeatedly and when it finished it calls scrollViewDidEndZooming. All as you would expect.

However, if you implement your own pinch gesture recognizer to make the zoom smoother or for any other reason, it only calls viewForZoomingInScrollView at the start and scrollViewDidZoom repeatedly. I think this is because you have overridden the built in zoom functionality that calls the other methods.

If you need more control put it into an action method connected to the pinch gesture recogniser.